# When is a question off-topic because it asks for documentation?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, scope

Recently, I reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106883/function-names-with-symbol-characters-makes-googling-difficult) in Triage. It was a test designed to check whether I paid attention, so nothing bad happen. However, I marked the question as off-topic, because it clearly asks for documentation, not a programming problem:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it.

But obviously, many people and SO's question algorithm thinks different and considers the question as very good. Can someone please explain me why? Is it because the OP credibly said that it's hard to find documentation?

I think, my question just adds to [the bunch of meta-questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+question+off-topic+documentation) of other confused people. Maybe we should refine SO's definition of off-topic and/or adhere more to it?

Comment: Some of those review audits are terrible...

Comment: He's not asking for documentation, he asking for a fish.  Finding a way to help yourself when Google will not co-operate is generally useful to many Haskell programmers.  Avoid red-button reviewing, never hesitate Skip when the [tag] is far out of your comfort-zone.

Comment: "Is it because the OP credibly said that it's hard to find documentation?" Yes, I would consider that a valid exception to the off-site resource rule. Documentation is an important tool -- if it's generally considered hard to find then that warrants a topic.

Comment: @HansPassant: What exactly is red-button reviewing?